# javascript primitives vs object references

Tags: javascript, variables, object, reference, primitive

I've been using JavaScript for years and this one has me stumped. As I understood things, when defining a `var`, one of two things will happen:

1. If the expression is a primitive, `var` is defined as a new instance of that primitive with no reference to the passed expression.
2. If the expression is an object literal, a new object is created.
3. If the expression is an existing object, `var` will reference the object and any future changes to the object will be reflected.

However, I've run into a situation where case 3 doesn't apply:

```
var obj = {body: {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}};

var ref = obj.body;
ref = JSON.stringify(ref);

console.log(typeof ref); // string
console.log(typeof obj.body); // object
```

Since `ref` is defined as the `body` property of `obj`, I thought redefining `ref` as a string also would affect `obj.body`. So what am I missing?

Comment: you overwrite the variable, it is not going to change what is in the object....

Comment: I think the confusion comes from the fact that `ref = ...` does not mutate the object it points to. If you mutated `ref` (by setting `ref.a = 5` for example) you would see the updates via both references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JSON.stringify` is a method which takes an object and returns its string representation, it doesn't change anything. By doing `ref = x` you make `ref` point to another thing, it doesn't affect what was there before assignment.

Comment: I'm still confused. If `ref` references `obj.body`, and then I did `ref = 'foo'`, wouldn't `obj.body` be redefined as `'foo'`?

Answer (score 0):

That simply means, you are no more referencing `obj.body`.body and referencing to something else.

```
var ref = obj.body; 

//ref holding obj.body now any changes to ref will effect obj.body.

ref = JSON.stringify(ref);

//ref holding a String returned by `stringify()` now any changes to ref will effect obj.body.
```

You see ?? You just changing the `ref` with different values. Not really changing anything on `obj`

Answer (score 0):

Primitives are immutable. If there’s a difference in how they would behave compared to objects, you can’t observe that, so forget all that stuff about copying. Let’s talk instead in terms of “things”! Objects and primitives are both things. When you assign a thing to a variable, you are not copying the thing.

```
var x = literally any value;
var y = x;
```

`x` and `y` are both variables that contain the same thing. If you change the thing, it doesn’t matter where you access it from in the future; the thing changed. If you change the thing the variable contains, the thing it contained before is not affected.

```
var z = some other value;
y = z;  // y now contains the same thing as z instead of the same thing as x
        // only variables changed, and the things did not
```

There are a lot of answers that talk about this in other terms but I enjoy technical language.

**tl;dr**: For all intents and purposes, the distinction between objects and primitives in JavaScript is not a useful one.

**ts;iwrse**: [This article about Python](http://foobarnbaz.com/2012/07/08/understanding-python-variables/) applies to JavaScript just as much.

Comment: long form comments ftw